# How to count the amount of white Pixels time efficiently in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am trying to compare two bitmaps to one another. One is premade, and the other one consists of a small image of the main screen being taken and filtered for everything besides full white. I now need a way to compare the amount of white pixels in the live Bitmap to the amount in the premade Bitmap (101 white pixels). A way I know of would be using the Bitmap.Get/SetPixel commands, but they are really slow and as this is used for a kind of time critical application, unfitting.
Especially since I could cut down the filtering process by a factor of 70 by following this guide.

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/617613/fast-pixel-operations-in-net-with-and-without-unsa

I also can't just compare the 2 Bitmaps, as the live one will usually not have the pixels in the same position, but will share the same amount of white pixels.

So yeah. It'd be great if one of you had a time effective solution to this problem.

**Edit**

 Huge oversight on my part. When looking at the filtering method, it becomes apparent that one can just use a `counter+=1` every time a pixel is not filtered out.
So I just changed this line of code in the filter function

`row[rIndex] = row[bIndex] = row[gIndex] = distance > toleranceSquared ? unmatchingValue : matchingValue;`

to this

```
if(distance > toleranceSquared)
{
row[rIndex] = row[bIndex] = row[gIndex] = unmatchingValue;
}
else
{
    row[rIndex] = row[bIndex] = row[gIndex] = matchingValue;
    WhitePixelCount += 1;
}
```

Comment: Well the link is interesting and the 3rd piece of code shows an example of using LockBits. There are many other exaples around and this is clearly the most efficient way to access pixels.

Comment: I actually used the unsafe Variant, and it gave the best performance by far. 8ms/run
I just don't know how to implement it as to get the amount of white pixels out of the array.

Comment: Lockbits and unsafe should have very similar performance. So, if your code works, ie if you can access the piixls/colors what is missing?

Comment: I still have not found a way to actually count the amount of pixels that are still in the Bitmap from the Primary Screen. I will try it with a byte array and for loops and post an update if it works.

Comment: If counting white pixels is time-critical, consider using an imaging SDK like LEADTOOLS (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). You could use methods like `rasterImage.AddColorToRegion(RasterColor.White, ...)` and `rasterImage.CalculateRegionArea()` to get the count of white pixels. You could also use `rasterImage.AddColorRgbRangeToRegion(colorLow, colorHigh, ...)` to count near-white pixels. I tested with a 2-million pixels image and it counted in 4 milliseconds. With smaller image (100,000 pixels), it took less than 0.3 ms. You can try [free evaluation here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).